# VBA/Excel Find a string in a cell to determine the next cell's value

Tags: vba, excel

I need to find a string in a cell, and if that string is found, the cell next to it has to put that string in the next cell.  In layman's terms:

```
IF "Medina" is found in a C3
    put "ME" in cell D3;
ELSEIF "Brunswick" is found in C3
    put "BR" in D3;
ELSE 
    put "OTH"in D3;
```

And this has to go through out the sheet, i.e., C4 & D4, C5 & D5, etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for `Medina` in with a string of other letters?

Comment: Do you need this to loop through a certain number of cells or until it hits blank cells? Additionally, do you need it entirely automated in VBA? Otherwise you could just do `=IF(C3="Medina","ME",IF(C3="Brunswick","BR","OTH"))`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for the `InStr` function (see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx). Basically we want to check if there is a non-zero answer for this, which indicates the string can be found.

So you could do something like below. Note I just put in 40 as your last row arbitrarily, but you can change this as you need.

```
Dim indStartRow As Integer
Dim indEndRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

indStartRow = 3
indEndRow = 40

For i = indStartRow To indEndRow
    If InStr(Sheets("Sheetname").Range("C" & i).Value, "Medina") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheetname").Range("D" & i).value = "ME"
    ElseIf InStr(Sheets("Sheetname").Range("C" & i).Value, "Brunswick") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheetname").Range("D" & i).value = "BR"
    Else
        Sheets("Sheetname").Range("D" & i).value = "OTH"
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need VBA for this, Excel Formulas are sufficient. If you want your Selection criteria to be easily extendable, use this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($AB$1:$AB$2,MATCH($A1,$AA$1:$AA$2,0)),"Other")
```

This Formula is in B1, while A1 contains Medina, Brunswick, etc. AA1:AA2 contain Medina...Brunswick and AAB1:AAB2 ME...BR. It can be moved to a different sheet, and you can extend it by selecting the last cell and inserting whole rows. Later you may want to use named ranges, too.